# porcentajes en barplot

Tags: r, rstudio

Si creo un barplot de esta forma

```
a<-as.matrix(c(0.75, 0.25))
b<-as.matrix(c(0.33, 0.66)) 
count<-cbind(a,b) 
barplot(count, main="Gráficos apilados", names.arg=c("Otoño","Primavera"),  xlab = "Características", col=c("gainsboro", "pink"), legend=c("op 1", "op. 2"))
```

Se le puede agregar al gráfico los porcentajes, o sea que estén los números en el mismo gráfico?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es posible calcular al vuelo las coordenadas de las etiquetas, para evitar tener que ubicar las mismas "a mano":

```
ys <- apply(count, 2, function(x) c(x[1]/2, head(cumsum(x),-1) + tail(x,-1)/2))
xs <- barplot(count, 
        main="Gráficos apilados", 
        names.arg=c("Otoño","Primavera"),  
        xlab = "Características", 
        col=c("gainsboro", "pink"), legend=c("op 1", "op. 2"))

text(rep(xs, each=nrow(ys)), c(ys), labels=c(count))
```

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre que puedes ponerlo directo utilizando `text`, por ejemplo

```
text(0.75,0.4,"75%")
text(0.75,0.9,"25%")
```

para la primer barra.

Saludos